# Generated subgroups in an $p$-primary abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am having trouble understanding the extra assumptions given in this problem:

> Assume $\{y_1,...,y_t\}\subset G$ where $G$ is an abelian $p$-primary group,with
>
> $<y_1,..,y_t>=<y_1>\oplus...\oplus <y_t>$
>
> and $z_1,...,z_t$ are elements of $G $ with $pz_i=y_i$, for all $i$, prove that
>
> $<z_1,..,z_t>=<z_1>\oplus...\oplus <z_t>$

(*Note: A group G is called $p$-primary if every element $x\in G$ has order some power of p.*)

From my understandings of this problem, you don't need to be given

> $<y_1,..,y_t>=<y_1>\oplus...\oplus <y_t>$

I thought that in general given any subset of elements $\{g_1,...,g_s\}$ in an abelian group $G^*$ that $<g_1,...,g_s>=<g_1>\oplus ...\oplus <g_s>$

so why the need for the extra structure? Unless of course the structure isn't needed then you can just respond with "it isn't needed."

Edit: I now realize there is an obvious counter example to the claim "given any subset of elements $\{g_1,...,g_s\}$ in an abelian group $G^*$ that $<g_1,...,g_s>=<g_1>\oplus ...\oplus <g_s>$", what I meant to say is that $<g_1,...,g_s>$ cannot be "reduced" (i.e. every element $g_i$ cannot be rewritten as a sum of the the other elements $\sum\limits_{j\neq i}m_jg_j$).

Comment: Consider two generators $x$ and $y$ of any finite cyclic group $G$. Certainly $ G = \langle x, y \rangle \not\cong \langle x \rangle \oplus \langle y \rangle \cong G \oplus G.$

Comment: So excluding redundancy given a set $<x_1,...,x_n>$  that is "reduced" (each element $x_i$ cannot be written as a sum of the others), then does the equality follow?